# Sendmail return true but doesnt send the mail

Tags: php, sendmail

I have already read some of the articles here. But nobody fits to my problem. I used sendmail for my wamp server. Yes, it returns true "Message sent" but when I check the email there is no message. I wonder why. I even watch many tutorials in youtube and follow the instruction step by step.

```
<?php
$to ='espadadave@yahoo.com';
$subject='Notification';
$message='You have just received an email notification';
$headers='From: love95@gmail.com' . "\r\n" .
'Reply-To: love95@gmail.com';
if ( mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers))
echo "message sent";
else
echo "not sent";
?>
```

Comment: Do you test on your localhost?

Comment: yes.. Its always message sent.. but i have said i doesnt actually send. I didnt received the message.

Comment: Do you use XAMPP or somethin similar?

Answer (score 0):

try this $headers

$headers = 'From:love95@gmail.com' . "\r\n" .

'Reply-To: 'Reply-To: love95@gmail.com' . "\r\n" .

"Content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8" . "\r\n";

'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();

Comment: Code blocks on their own are not usually useful answers. Please explain what the code you're showing does, and why/how that code answers the question.

Comment: $msg and $to seems okay to me so the only thing that affect this might be the $header,

Comment: The Problem is unlikely to be in the mail itselfs ist more a Server configuration issue

Comment: in this case @Danilo Escapa should give us the complete information

Comment: He propably does't know thats a ServerFault else he would has (hopefully) posted into the ServerFault Community

Answer (score 0):

The function `mail()` returning true means that the mail was successfully transferred to the corresponding SMTP server. You can't control if the server really sends the message or if it reached the recipient.

Answer (score 0):

True messages from mail function is meaning that your e-mail is added the mail queue. You should check sendmail logs and mail queue.

http://www.electrictoolbox.com/show-sendmail-mail-queue/

http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-unix-bsd-clear-sendmail-queue/

Answer (score 0):

When you use XAMPP or similar normaly there is no SMTP Server to send the Mails.

So have a look into the Folder `mailoutput` or something like it.

The server saves the messages as .txt Files in that Folder.

If you actually want to send Messages you Need to install a Mailserver. (Somteimes there is one already in the Package but not activated)

Answer (score 0):

1) If you are using Localhost, you need to install a mailing server
2) Check your spam folder in mailbox
3) Try using phpmailer or swiftmailer lib 
4) Check your message filtering settings

Comment: If I used phpmailer or swiftmailer do I need to remove the sendmail folder??

Comment: Hey Danilo, No need to remove sendmail folder.

Comment: After I download what should I do? Where i should extract it?